# Setting up a 2nd Rackspace Cloud Server as slave dedicated db server in my cluster - 1 15GB slave or 2 8GB?

Tags: magento-1.8, database, mysql

So as the title states, I am going to set up a second RackSpace cloud server as a slave DB on my Magento cluster.  Currently, I have one of their 15GB Performance 2 servers as my DB, but I would like to set up a slave for reads.   I just noticed that Magento can support more than just the 1 slave, so I am curious if it might offer more performance to set up 2 8GB Performance 1s  as the read slaves, with the existing 15GB Performance 2 as the write slave.  The financial cost is pretty much the same.

What do you think?  I am currently running Magento CE 1.8.  Thank you!

Comment: Or heck, is that even too much?  Should I just try a single 8GB Perf 1 as the read slave?  Here is a link to their server stats: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers/pricing/

Comment: Hosting should be 0.5-1% of revenue which is the easy calcuation, revenue needs to be in the $millions to justify those costs so presume you are running EE. No stats provided but more servers means more monitoring and realistically like for like otherwise replication may fall behind causing unintented consequences. Consistency is key.

Answer (score 4):

In **all of my experience** I've only ever seen **one Magento store** that was actually DB-bound, and it was a special case wherein they were running a wealth of business intelligence queries against their **live** database. After some time (and a db slave later) we set up a warehousing strategy that alleviated the strain on the DB.

I don't know your specifics (i.e. traffic, order volume, spikes/peaks) but I can tell you that running multiple db's opens you up to a whole new world of issues - especially on cloud. In my experience DB read slaves can lag *just* far enough behind to cause some race condition issues such as order placement or Paypal IPN issues during checkout. The problems are exacerbated when indexing as in some cases you can wind up **being minutes behind the master** as index jobs can take a while to run and commit to the table.

MySQL binlogging is pretty I/O intensive from what I understand (I'm not a DBA, and I do not play one on TV) and creates at least **a little overhead** on the master - if this is true it will actually **decrease** the performance of your master by a minute amount.

You **really should know** what you're doing wading into this territory. If you're looking for speed gains you'd be better served by beefing up your Apache boxes or balancing traffic between them, setting up memcached/redis and upgrading your I/O or networking capabilities on your Rackspace Cloud boxes. Also, consider moving to dedicated hardware at least for your DB. I am a huge Rackspace advocate - but make sure you speak with experts on the topic at RS; or at least hit up some of the brilliant minds at Nexcess or Sonassi before you make this decision.

My $0.02. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have done quite a few sites now on Rackspace and I think your biggest concern is the amount of RAM you have in your database server. If you DB is only 2gb then I think the 8/* performance one server will work. But if you database is 10GB then the 4/15 maybe the better option. The Rackers (and your account rep) will be able to give you some good feed back. There are also a couple of REALLY good Magento techs on 2nd shift. I would try to track one of them done.

One thing I would be aware of on their cloud is the I/O time on high traffic. If you end up with a lot of traffic it maybe better to do a hybrid environment (Dedicated DB/Cloud frontend). Your Rep can connect the two for you if you ask!

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it. As philwinkle said the slave can be lots of seconds behind the master. Our live db is > 50 GB and sometimes the slave is 2 hours "later" if we have really heavy traffic or import something.

We use a db slave only to create dumps for dev and stage because dumping from live costs to much performance.

But there is also another issue: 
Some years ago we had some experiements with read and write queries against slave and master. We checked that the Magento guys did not implemented it correctly over all. We had some write queries against slave and stopped all further tests. Maybe with Magento 1.9x it is fixed.